# How do you design FirebaseAuthentication when building a system with users with multiple roles?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am considering using FirebaseAuthentication for login authentication of my new web system.
It's like a recruitment site.
It has users seekers and companies.
The database is going to use MySQL.

When managing these two types of users, is it necessary to prepare two Firebase projects?
Or should I classify users in the database, so should Firebase projects be one?

Please let me hear your thoughts on design.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is a very broad question and impossible to answer completely. Firebase has no notion of user types; a user is a user. If you want some users to be different than other users you could for example, store their type along with other user data in a /users node like this */users/uid_0/type: "seeker"* and */users/uid_1/type: "companies"* and when they authenticate, read that type from their user node. And yes, they would all be within a single project. Also, since you will be using Firebase, why also add MySQL? Firebase is a fast and powerful real-time, event driven database so why not use it?

Comment: Why do you want to have two separate firebase projects? It's the same app? I think the real question is how do you intend to use the user data? How are you going to manage the users and their roles? Maybe you want to check Firebase custom claims, or have a table in your MySQL database with each user's role. Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I had never used firebase in my business, so I wanted advice from experienced people. I am aware that Relational Database is more robust than NoSQL like Firestore, so I would like to use MySQL.